# Compile errror in remix doesn't make the thing clear

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens

Doing lesson 5 from here [how to write smart-contract, lesson 5](http://inaword.ru/blokchejn/pishem-smart-kontrakt-ethereum-eto-prosto-chast-5-token-erc20/) I got compile error in remix. It goes:

> browser/ballot.sol:40:2: ParserError: Expected pragma, import
>   directive or contract/interface/library definition.  function
>   approve(address _spender, uint _value) public constant returns (bool
>   success){

and the full code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SimpleTokenCoin{

string public constant name = "Simple Coin Token";

string public constant symbol = "SCT";

uint32 public constant decimals = 18;

uint public totalSupply = 0;

mapping (address => uint) balances;

function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint balance){ return balances[_owner]; }

function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success){ if(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value >= balances[_to]){ balances[msg.sender] -=_value; balances[_to] += value; Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); return true; } return false; }

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success){ if(balances[_from] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value >= balances[_to]){
balances[_from] -=_value; balances[_to] += value; Transfer(_from, _to, _value); return true; } return false; } }

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public constant returns (bool success){ return false; }

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant retuns (uint256 remaining){ return 0; }

function mint(address _to, uint _value) public { assert(totalSupply + _value >= totalSupply && balances[_to] +_value >= balances[_to]); balances[_to] += _value; totalSupply += _value;
}

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint value);

event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value); 
}
```

Comment: The second guess in my answer is correct. I think that if you format your code properly, you'll see the issue. Make sure you indent every time you have an open curly brace and unindent when you have a closing curly brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to share your full code for us to know for sure, but my guess is that you're not defining a contract. Your code should look something like this:

```
contract MyContract {
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public constant returns (bool success) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It could also be that you closed the contract too early. In general, the error probably means you tried to define a function outside of a contract.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `r` on the `returns` part of the `allowance` function

I would also suggest for future problems like this use an IDE like Remix to spot syntax and almost all other errors (excluding logic errors of course)

Comment: I use remix  yes

Comment: I accepted another one by smarx,  it was made earlier and right at the point